# Can Atom work with Python virtualenvwrapper

Tags: python, virtualenv, atom-editor, virtualenvwrapper

I want to start a Flask app. I installed virtualenvwrapper to manage the packages but I can't let Atom know that the current project should use the virtualenv's python binary.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
```

Using Atom's script runner, I get an "ImportError: No module named flask".

I don't want the hassle of having to change to a terminal to run the app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the [virtualenv](https://atom.io/packages/virtualenv) package for Atom?

Comment: I've searched for it in the install link. Could not find it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that the package was so out of date. It looks a bit more involved, but https://atom.io/packages/python-jedi ought to get the job done.

Comment: Try to use the new Atom support for virtualenvs: https://github.com/pghilardi/atom-python-virtualenv

Comment: atom-python-virtualenv only works for *nix systems. Finally, a reason to use Docker!

Comment: @Nearoo UPDATE: This package works in UNIX and WINDOWS systems.

Answer (score 31):

In Linux:

1. Start your virtual environment python.
2. Launch atom from your python virtual environment.

   ```
   (EVP) abc $ atom
   ```

That's all.

Comment: and on macOS 10.13.1

Answer (score 3):

I am the creator of a new package that adds support to virtualenv inside Atom: [Atom Python Virtualenv](https://atom.io/packages/atom-python-virtualenv)

You can **select a virtualenv, create a new one or deactivate**, all of this inside Atom.

Feel free to contribute to the project on [github](https://github.com/pghilardi/atom-python-virtualenv).

Answer (score 0):

I played around with linter-pylint 2.1.1 package installed in Atom 1.38.2 x64 and work a lot in virtual environments (using conda activate). I got Pylint and Atom to play nice (so far!) with the following settings. You need to check the "Disable Execution Timeout", otherwise it likely will timeout.

[image]