# Module Not Found in python script

Tags: python, windows, import, atom-editor

I'm a python beginner, and I'm following this tutorial for a webscraper https://hackernoon.com/building-a-web-scraper-from-start-to-finish-bb6b95388184

I'm on Windows 10, have setup a venv, activated and installed 2 modules using pip, and moved my script into the `Scripts` folder (from my understanding, this is the equivalent of the `/bin/` folder on linux installations).  The modules are `bs4` and `requests`.  I see both of these in the `/Lib/` folder of my venv.  I am using the Atom editor from atom.io, and the Scripts Package to run my script.

My script errors with a "module not found" error.  Relevant snippet below:

```py
scraper.py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
```

I get the error on both imports, indicating I've setup my project/imports incorrectly.  I have no shebang line in my script, and suspect this is the problem.

My project structure looks like:

```
\ScraperProject
 |-\ScrEnv
  |-\Include
  |-\Lib
   |-\site-packages
    |-\bs4
    |-\requests
  |-\Scripts
   |-scraper.py
  |-pyvenv.cfg
```

What is the proper way for me to import these modules into my script in a Windows environment?

Comment: did you activate the virtual environment correctly?

Comment: I ran `python -m venv ScrEnv`, then used `ScrEnv\Scripts\activate.bat` to activate it, followed by `pip install bs4` and `pip install requests` while the new venv was activated.  I do not have a python3 executable, but have Python 3.7.4 installed, and get no errors using the above commands to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

with what python version are you working in the venv? Maybe try to uninstall those update pip and  reinstall those again, making sure that you install them with pyhton3

Comment: I've installed the current version of Python on Windows, python 3.7.4.  I'll try running through the venv setup again making sure to specify python3 and let you know how it goes.

Comment: The windows install only creates a `python.exe` in the C:\Users\rivards\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37 folder, which is added to my `PATH` env variable.  I set it up using `python -m venv ScrEnv`, then used `ScrEnv\Scripts\activate.bat` to activate it, followed by `pip install bs4` and `pip install requests` while the new venv was activated.  I do get a warning about a newer version of pip existing, it's on pip 19.0.3 and 19.2.3 exists.  I have not upgraded it.  Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

My issue is related to running it from the Atom editor, something I hadn't considered before.  It's calling the `python` executable from my PATH variable, and not the one in my venv.  When running the script from the cmd window, and calling it with the `python` from my project folder/venv, it runs as expected.  On to figuring out how to configure Atom to use the venv executables.  Thank you very much for the interest and help!

Comment: This other question is the real solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36706039/can-atom-work-with-python-virtualenvwrapper